# How to disable automatic weapon switching?

Tags: half-life-2

When a new weapon or a weapon which has ran out of ammo and is no longer in the inventory (grenade; there may be more) is picked up the game equips the item, the feature is sometimes called as "auto weapon switch". Half-Life 2 doesn't detect `cl_autowepswitch 0` command.

Comment: Is it not an option in the regular options? I remember unchecking a box there for weapon switching.

Comment: @mmatthews: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug introduced by the 2010 Orange Box engine update. From [the pinned bug report thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20160830085422/http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1286478) on the now-closed former Steam forums:

> **Bug Title**: Auto weapon switch always on.
>
> **Bug Description**: Cannot turn autoweapon switch off "cl_autowepswitch
> 0" is unknown command.